# Cannot get drop downs to populate in Safari

Tags: php, mysql, safari

I am populating two html drop downs using php/mysql.  They work fine in Firefox/Opera/Chrome and even IE but not Safari.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I have scoured the web for hints to no avail.

You can see the application live here: http://www.plastproinc.com/fiberglass-entry-doors/catalog/home.php?frm=link  Step 2 is the problem (does not matter what you choose for step 1).

I did not write this part of the code originally and I am not in touch with the original developer, so I would really appreciate some advice.  The code for one of the selects (after the query) is:

```
<div id="selectbox1">    
 <select name="websites2" id="websites2" style="width:125px;" onchange="setWidthHeight(this.value,'h');">
  <option name="zero" value="0" title="" selected="selected">Select Height</option>
  <?php
  if ($sizenumh > 0) 
  {
   $j = 0;
   while ($j < $sizenumh) 
   {
    $height_id = mysql_result($sizeresulth,$j,"id");    
    $height = mysql_result($sizeresulth,$j,"height");   
    ?>
    <option name="<?php echo $height_id ?>" value="<?php echo $height ?>" title=""><?php echo $height ?></option>
    <?php
    $j++;
   }
  }
  ?>
 </select>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I knew it was something easy but that I should have caught.  Works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: I've answered so please accept as correct answer by ticking checkmark, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to post this as an answer, rather than a comment (I miss the necessary reputation to post comments). But for me it seems to work on Safari (version 5.1.1, running on Windows 7).

Comment: It was not working on Safari 5.1 on XP, but is ok now that I changed the name to an id.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

`option` tag has no `name` attribute.